# @angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Version'

Tags: angular

When doing a npm install I get this error when I run the Application as well as my tests. It refers the '@angular/http' module as the base of the error

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the mismatch of the versions of your @angular dependencies, make sure your dependencies are of the same version, following is my **package.json** file.

```js
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
```